# Get-ChildItem not working with long UNC path

Tags: powershell, path, unc, get-childitem

I try to use long UNC paths with `Get-ChildItem` in Powershell like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\?\c:\blabla"
```

and Powershell says that there are illegal characters in the path. The very same path works with `Resolve-Path`. How can I use the "\\?\" syntax with `gci`?

Comment: If you aren't doing any variable substitution, you can try either `-LiteralPath "yourpath"` or using single quotes `-Path 'PathWithSpecialChars'`

Comment: I do not use variables atm. However, I found that using the admin share C$ instead of C: does not produce the Syntax error, but `gci` does not have any output either.

Comment: Additionally, `gci "\\?\UNC\c:\blabla"` does not yield the syntax error, but has no results, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great news! **PowerShell v6.0.0-beta.3 and up now supports UNC paths by default**; it automatically prepends the UNC string to paths > 260 characters:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.3
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3960
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3960/files/3e7e28d49f306ab4874e32cf10eabb43559dae26#diff-52b1a915619c71b288b3f92f944924c4

> Fix PowerShell Core to allow the use of long paths that are more than 260 characters. (#3960)
>
> ...
>
> When calling Windows native API to determine if an item exists, ensure the path is prepended with \?\ to allow for paths > 260 characters.

---

You simply have to download that version or later (via. the [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) tags). I just downloaded [v6.0.0-beta.9](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/v6.0.0-beta.9) for Windows x64 onto my Windows 10 machine and tested it out, creating a path with some 460 characters!

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find an incantation that works with `?`. However the following do work:

```
gci '\\localhost\C$\'
gci ('\\{0}\C$\' -f $ENV:COMPUTERNAME)
```

Update:
Reference: [UNC path does not work with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009013/unc-path-does-not-work-with-net)

The `\\?\` portion is windows specific and essentially does the same thing as `--%` in powershell, which is to say 'Everything after this is a literal string'

Example:

```
$LongUncPath = '\\?\C:\'
Get-ChildItem -Path:$LongUncPath.TrimStart('\\?\')
```

Comment: That is what I see, too. UNC works, but long UNC does not. The problem is that I need long UNC. Does anyone know whether long UNC is not working *by design*? I would need to search for a workaround then...

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had non-printable characters at the end of my path.  I corrected "Illegal characters in path" by use of trim() to remove them.

$path.trim()