# Get all files in folder including those with long (>256 characters) path + name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a comma separated list of file names in a specific folder. These files tend to have long names (they're test case results and the name is very descriptive).

I've found that Get-ChildItem ignores files whose name (including path) is too long.

```
# Folder contains the following file (240 chars, actual name is 'only' 210 chars):
# SomeServiceWithAnAlreadyLongNameUnderTest_NameOfTheParticularTestSuiteThatProducedThisResult-NameOfTheActualMethodUnderTest-Given_A_Certain_Precondition_Is_Met_WhenCalling_With_Someparameter_As_SomeValue_Then_Result_Is_Something-Failed.txt
Get-ChildItem *.txt -name
# I would have loved for this to work:
(Get-ChildItem *.txt -name) -join ','
```

The result does not include the file, since the path+filename are too long. There's no error or warning either.

As a work around I'm using a cmd script file with for:

```
for %%a in (%XMLPath%\*.xml) do ( ... build comma separated list with %%a ... )
```

How can I the full list including (too?) long names in Powershell?

Comment: Try using [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles() to obtain you paths collection and work with that.

Comment: Also try prefixing your path with \\?\

Comment: @MartinMaat, GetFiles() has the same limitation.

Comment: PowerShell is build on .NET which does not support long file paths. Check this out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204186/error-file-path-is-too-long

Comment: If you want to build your own .NET assembly (to Add-Type into your PowerShell script) that works around this limitation by addressing Win32 system calls, this may help:   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19688/In-C-Use-Win-API-to-Enumerate-File-and-Directory

Comment: FYI UNC paths are now supported by default in PowerShell v6.0.0-beta.3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046785/1599699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a really popular question because it has been asked multiple times on this site.Anyway here are your alternatives:

**Use Pinvoke**

[Boe Prox - Technet](https://github.com/proxb/PInvoke/blob/master/Get-ChildItem2.ps1)

**Use Robocopy**

[Boe Prox - Technet](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/01/list-all-files-regardless-of-260-character-path-restriction-using-powershell-and-robocopy/)

**Use AlphaFS with Powershell V5 and V4**

if you can find a computer with PowerShell v5 (windows 10 comes with PS v5) you can install a module called [PSAlphaFS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAlphaFS/) .

```
Install-Module PSAlphaFS
```

by default the modules from powershellgallery get installed to

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

Note:The PSAlphaFS module can also be run on a target system with PowerShell V4 but not on powershell V3.

Here is how you can find out the version of Powershell that is currently running.

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

Once the module is in place you can
then run the following command which is similar to get-childitem but without the 260 char limitation.

```
Get-LongChildItem  -Filter *.txt -Name
```

Comment: Now that I know what I'm searching for I can suddenly find tons of info. Thank you!

Comment: FYI UNC paths are now supported by default in PowerShell v6.0.0-beta.3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046785/1599699

Comment: The link for Boe Prox's script is no longer valid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=TechNet-Gallery

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is no straightforward way to handle this situation using PowerShell. To me that means PowerShell is not the right tool for this job and I'm going to use my "work-around" cmd script instead.

Comment: It's a limitation in the .net frameworks, and not pr say in Powershell. But still, Powershell is build apon .net so in some sens, Powershell inherit this limitation. But I would disagree, that it's not the right tool. There is planty og great tools you can use to help Powershell, and not as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell v6.0.0-beta.3 and up now supports UNC paths by default**; see my answer here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046785/1599699