# PowerShell Rename-Item on Long Named Files Warning Removal

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I try to rename files with PwerShell Rename-Item cmdlet. Code below

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse * `
  | ?{!$_.PsIsContainer} `
  | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName -Replace '.abcd@email.com','.abcd@email_A.com.abcd@email_B.com.abcd@email_E.com'}
```

But, PowerShel tells me about long path or file name; which is irrelevant to my process. But it is strongly necessary keep new long name.

How to except this error?

Comment: `-NewName` should be **string** (but `{}`indicate a  _ScriptBlock_) Use something like `-NewName $($_.FullName -Replace '.abcd@email.com','.abcd@email_A.com.abcd@email_B.com.abcd@email_E.com')`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer. If I do like you mentioned, I get error with message: "Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null."

Comment: @JosefZ see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/06/23/flexible-pipelining-with-scriptblock-parameters/ section "ScriptBlock Parameters" - passing a scriptblock as a parameter which doesn't specify a scriptblock type is valid and it will be dynamically evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all files in folder including those with long (>256 characters) path + name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459752/get-all-files-in-folder-including-those-with-long-256-characters-path-name) - if not a direct duplicate of this, one of many "long path error" questions, which this has some links to. Short answer: there's no easy way round it. Long answer: you call out to lower level APIs, custom modules, or install Windows 10 latest and edit the registry

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler maybe however I'd prefer a conservative approach with `Foreach-Object`. Moreover, `-NewName` might not allow a path and name. I'd use either `Move-Object` or  (changed) `$_.Name`.

Comment: @JosefZ is it possible ask you about code example? I'm new in PowerShell commands.

Comment: Renaming an item implies that it stays at the same folder, so don't use `$_.FullName` but `$_.Name` to **only** change the name. Otherwise use Move-Item as already suggested.

Comment: Although I didnot get the error and operationally it worked properly. Still suggesting [XYExplorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/)

Comment: Yes, change `$_.fullname` to `$_.name`.  And you can use `get-childitem -file`.  And test `rename-item` with `-whatif`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**is it possible ask you about code example?** The following *commented* code snippet (conservative approach) could help:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse * | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | 
  ForEach-Object {
    ###  in regular expression:  ↓           ↓   escape dots
    $NewName = $_.Name -Replace '\.abcd@email\.com',
      '.abcd@email_A.com.abcd@email_B.com.abcd@email_E.com'

    ### here is right place to check target filename length:
    $targetLength = 1 + $_.DirectoryName.Length + $NewName.Length

    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName
  }
```

Read [Rename-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Rename-Item) reference and [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).